# In monaco editor, is there an event for catching format event?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, monaco-editor

```
cont editor = monaco.editor.create(element, {
            value: text,
            language: mode,
            automaticLayout: true,
            autoIndent: true,
            contextmenu: false,
            formatOnType: true
        });
editor.trigger('any', 'editor.action.formatDocument');
```

Is there a way to pass a callback to the trigger method, or catch an event for the format finished action?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/115

Comment: Thanks @HardikShah, I  am not sure this is the exact same thing, since my editor is ready. I would like to know when the format has finished. I the bug, they needed to know when to start the format action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax will run the console.log statement after the action has been executed, using a promise.

```
editor.getAction('editor.action.formatDocument').run().then(() => console.log('finished'));
```

Answer from:

https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/978